# Remove password from 2007 word document while actual password doesn't work

Tags: passwords, microsoft-word-2007

How do I remove password protection from a 2007 word document (docx)?
When entering the right password I get an error message telling me the password would be wrong. But: I'm definetly sure it is right. I tried several methods like renaming it to *.htm ([Unprotect a Word Document](https://superuser.com/questions/96242/unprotect-a-word-document)), *.zip or *.rtf but nothing helped.

Any ideas on solving this problem?

Comment: Just a simple _silly_ question: can you copy all the document (CTRL-A and CTRL-C) & paste all in a new document (CTRL-C)?

Comment: Are you able to open the file at all? As in, is it just edit protected, or do you have to enter the correct password to even open it?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.To remove passwords from MS Word.

1.Convert original word document in to Rich text format(.*rtf).

2.open that Rich text format(.*rtf) file using any of the text editor.

3.Search for "passwordhash".

4.It will display something like this.{ *\passwordhash ======}.

4.Delete the text between passwordhash and closing curely braces.

5.Then save the file and close the editor.

6.open that  Rich text format file(.*rtf) using MS Word.

7.convert the ( .*rtf)format in to original fromat(*.docx).

8.click "stop protection" button in review tab.

Hope this helps.